# Добавление родительского тэга XML для существующего

Tags: java, xml, xmlparser

Пишу парсер для преобразования XML.

```java
public class TransformXML {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            String filepath  = "file:///C:\\Users\\Podolyak_EA\\Desktop\\Загрузка из xml\\примеры xml\\new\\75-2_.xml";
            DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = docBuilder.parse(filepath);
            // tag "Document" rename to "Form
            Node docTag = doc.getElementsByTagName("Document").item(0);
            doc.renameNode(docTag, "", "Form");
            //tag "powerFacilitiesVid" rename to "powerFacility"
            Node pFVtag = doc.getElementsByTagName("powerFacilitiesVid").item(0);
            //delete tag powerFacilitiesVid
            deleteChildElement(doc, "Form", pFVtag.getNodeName());
            String powerFacilityTag = "powerFacility";

            addChildElement(doc, "Form", powerFacilityTag);

            //add child tag "vid"

            NodeList taglist = doc.getElementsByTagName("powerFacility");
            Element el = null;
            for (int i = 0; i < taglist.getLength(); i++) {
                el = (Element) taglist.item(i);
                Element vid = doc.createElement("vid");
                vid.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("10888"));
                el.appendChild(vid);
            }
            Node itemTag = doc.getElementsByTagName("item").item(0);
            addParentElement(doc, itemTag);

            TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
            Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
            DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);

            StreamResult result = new StreamResult(filepath);

            transformer.transform(source, result);
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException pce) {
            pce.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        } catch (org.xml.sax.SAXException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (TransformerConfigurationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (TransformerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void addChildElement(Document doc, String parentTagName, String addedTag) {
        NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName(parentTagName);
        Element element = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
            element = (Element)nodeList.item(i);
            Element myElement = doc.createElement(addedTag);
            element.appendChild(myElement);
        }
    }

    public static void deleteChildElement(Document doc, String parentTagname, String deletedTag){
        NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName(parentTagname);
        Element element = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
            element = (Element)nodeList.item(i);
            Node deletedNode = element.getElementsByTagName(deletedTag).item(0);
            element.removeChild(deletedNode);
        }
    }

    public static void addParentElement( Document doc, Node currentChildNode) {        
    }  
}
```

Далее мне нужно обернуть существующий тэг вместе с его содержимым в родительский тэг.

Подскажите мне направление для написания метода `addParentElement`.

Answer (score 1):

Все таки написал метод самостоятельно.

```
public static void addParentElement( Document doc, Node childTag, Node parentsTag){
    NodeList itemList = doc.getElementsByTagName(childTag.getNodeName());
    for (int i = 0; i < itemList.getLength(); i++) {
        Element item = (Element) childTag;
        Element beanList = (Element) parentsTag;
        beanList.appendChild(item);
    }

}
```